# Add an array value in a loop?

Tags: jquery, arrays, push, slimbox

The slimbox should load multiple images in a row, but I don't know how to set up the for - loop.

The example of Slimbox2 tell me it should look like this:

```
jQuery.slimbox([["data/images/1.jpg"], ["data/images/2.jpg"], ["data/images/3.jpg"]], 0, {loop: true});
```

Here is what I have now:

```
var dataloop;
for (var i = 0; i < 35; ++i){
  dataloop = dataloop,+["data/images/"+i+".jpg"];
}
jQuery.slimbox([ dataloop ],0, {loop: true});
```

I've tried to .push it to an array, but it didn't worked either. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `var dataloop = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 35; ++i){
  dataloop.push(["data/images/"+i+".jpg"]);
}
jQuery.slimbox( dataloop ,0, {loop: true});` ???

Comment: Doing `.push` should work fine on an Array. Try defining your Array variable (`dataloop`?) like this `var dataloop = [];`, then you can use `dataloop.push("somevalue");`.

Comment: The answer from A.Wolff works great! My .push experiments went wrong because of some wrong quotes.